# Are there was to make this query script more efficient?

Tags: sql-server

I was given a task to create a query that, given a table, will do a batch aggregation on every 20 rows and produce a new table that has 5% of the rows of the given table. So if I'm given a 100 row table, the new table will be 5 rows where each row is an aggregation of rows: [1-20], [21-40], [41-60], [61-80], [81-100].

The purpose of this task is to determine the "Cycle" of a particular process where each cycle is a separate column "Cycle_X" where "X" is a number from 1 to 12. Each "Cycle_X" column is populated with a number from 0 to 4 that represents a priority; 0 means not prioritised. Each "Cycle" is supposed to be sequential, so "Cycle_1" precedes "Cycle_2" which precedes "Cycle_3" etc. The way my query determines the cycle for each mini-batch is by choosing the "Cycle_X" column in a batch with the minimum number of zeroes. To hopefully help clarify what I've explained above, here are images of a [simplified example base table](https://photos.app.goo.gl/8j1yFVSCKkjV5PFw8) and a [simplified example output table](https://photos.app.goo.gl/yWigyVz6Xd3TmVMB6) based on my description where it aggregates in batches of 5.

I've test my query on a dataset of 80k+ rows but it was never able to finish because the connection timed out, and now my datasets are over a million rows. Given the current situation, I am working remotely so I believe the remote connection isn't stable enough to to complete the process, but since I'm uncertain here is the exact error message:

> Msg 121, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)

The query I made first creates a base table for the batch aggregetion and an empty table to be populated with the batch aggregation. After declaring and setting some variables there is a while loop that populates the initially empty table one row at a time (one row from a min-batch of 20 rows from the base table) using an INSERT INTO statement. The minimum count of zeroes for the various cycles is determined using a massive CASE WHEN statement. The full query can be found below, I'd appreciate any help in making it more efficient. The only change I've made so far is to separate the table creation and the while loop into separate queries.

```
USE _dataBase

-- Create a temp table to perform batch aggregation on
CREATE TABLE dbo.baseTable
WITH (DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN) AS
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY _time) AS idx,
    _time,
    CASE WHEN Cycle_1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS z1, --logical index that detetcts zero and not zero
    CASE WHEN Cycle_2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS z2,
    CASE WHEN Cycle_3 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS z3,
    CASE WHEN Cycle_4 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS z4,
    CASE WHEN Cycle_5 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS z5,
    CASE WHEN Cycle_6 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS z6,
    CASE WHEN Cycle_7 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS z7,
    CASE WHEN Cycle_8 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS z8,
    CASE WHEN Cycle_9 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS z9,
    CASE WHEN Cycle_10 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS z10
FROM dbo.srcTable
WHERE _date = 20200423 --this must be parameterised

-- Create a table to store the batch aggregation (The table name should be parameterised somehow)
CREATE TABLE dbo.aggTable
(
    startTime datetime NOT NULL,
    endTime datetime NOT NULL,
    sum1 int NOT NULL,
    sum2 int NOT NULL,
    sum3 int NOT NULL,
    sum4 int NOT NULL,
    sum5 int NOT NULL,
    sum6 int NOT NULL,
    sum7 int NOT NULL,
    sum8 int NOT NULL,
    sum9 int NOT NULL,
    sum10 int NOT NULL,
    cycle int NOT NULL
)
--Declare variables
DECLARE
    @maxIter int, --The amount of times the loop runs
    @numRows int, --Number of rows in the temp table
    @batch int, --The size of the batch aggregation
    @offSet int, --The stat row of a batch that is updated during the loop
    @limit int, --The end row of a batch that is updated during the loop
    @iter int --Loop counter
--Set variables
SET @numRows = (SELECT COUNT(idx) FROM dbo.baseTable)
SET @maxIter = @numRows / 20
SET @batch = 20
SET @offSet = 1
SET @limit = 20
SET @iter = 0

--The loop
WHILE @iter < @maxIter
BEGIN
    --Append to this table
    INSERT INTO dbo.aggTable
    (
        startTime,
        endTime,
        sum1,
        sum2,
        sum3,
        sum4,
        sum5,
        sum6,
        sum7,
        sum8,
        sum9,
        sum10,
        cycle
    )
    SELECT
        MIN(_time) AS startTime,
        MAX(_time) AS endTime,
        SUM(z1) AS sum1, --this counts the number of zeroes for Cycle_1
        SUM(z2) AS sum2,
        SUM(z3) AS sum3,
        SUM(z4) AS sum4,
        SUM(z5) AS sum5,
        SUM(z6) AS sum6,
        SUM(z7) AS sum7,
        SUM(z8) AS sum8,
        SUM(z9) AS sum9,
        SUM(z10) AS sum10,
        --this case when clause is used to determine the Cycle basd on the minimum count of zeroes
        CASE
            WHEN SUM(z1) <= SUM(z2) AND SUM(z1) <= SUM(z3) AND SUM(z1) <= SUM(z4) AND SUM(z1) <= SUM(z5) AND SUM(z1) <= SUM(z6) AND SUM(z1) <= SUM(z7) AND SUM(z1) <= SUM(z8) AND SUM(z1) <= SUM(z9) AND SUM(z1) <= SUM(z10) THEN 1
            WHEN SUM(z2) <= SUM(z1) AND SUM(z2) <= SUM(z3) AND SUM(z2) <= SUM(z4) AND SUM(z2) <= SUM(z5) AND SUM(z2) <= SUM(z6) AND SUM(z2) <= SUM(z7) AND SUM(z2) <= SUM(z8) AND SUM(z2) <= SUM(z9) AND SUM(z2) <= SUM(z10) THEN 2
            WHEN SUM(z3) <= SUM(z1) AND SUM(z3) <= SUM(z2) AND SUM(z3) <= SUM(z4) AND SUM(z3) <= SUM(z5) AND SUM(z3) <= SUM(z6) AND SUM(z3) <= SUM(z7) AND SUM(z3) <= SUM(z8) AND SUM(z3) <= SUM(z9) AND SUM(z3) <= SUM(z10) THEN 3
            WHEN SUM(z4) <= SUM(z1) AND SUM(z4) <= SUM(z2) AND SUM(z4) <= SUM(z3) AND SUM(z4) <= SUM(z5) AND SUM(z4) <= SUM(z6) AND SUM(z4) <= SUM(z7) AND SUM(z4) <= SUM(z8) AND SUM(z4) <= SUM(z9) AND SUM(z4) <= SUM(z10) THEN 4
            WHEN SUM(z5) <= SUM(z1) AND SUM(z5) <= SUM(z2) AND SUM(z5) <= SUM(z3) AND SUM(z5) <= SUM(z4) AND SUM(z5) <= SUM(z6) AND SUM(z5) <= SUM(z7) AND SUM(z5) <= SUM(z8) AND SUM(z5) <= SUM(z9) AND SUM(z5) <= SUM(z10) THEN 5
            WHEN SUM(z6) <= SUM(z1) AND SUM(z6) <= SUM(z2) AND SUM(z6) <= SUM(z3) AND SUM(z6) <= SUM(z4) AND SUM(z6) <= SUM(z5) AND SUM(z6) <= SUM(z7) AND SUM(z6) <= SUM(z8) AND SUM(z6) <= SUM(z9) AND SUM(z6) <= SUM(z10) THEN 6
            WHEN SUM(z7) <= SUM(z1) AND SUM(z7) <= SUM(z2) AND SUM(z7) <= SUM(z3) AND SUM(z7) <= SUM(z4) AND SUM(z7) <= SUM(z5) AND SUM(z7) <= SUM(z6) AND SUM(z7) <= SUM(z8) AND SUM(z7) <= SUM(z9) AND SUM(z7) <= SUM(z10) THEN 7
            WHEN SUM(z8) <= SUM(z1) AND SUM(z8) <= SUM(z2) AND SUM(z8) <= SUM(z3) AND SUM(z8) <= SUM(z4) AND SUM(z8) <= SUM(z5) AND SUM(z8) <= SUM(z6) AND SUM(z8) <= SUM(z7) AND SUM(z8) <= SUM(z9) AND SUM(z8) <= SUM(z10) THEN 8
            WHEN SUM(z9) <= SUM(z1) AND SUM(z9) <= SUM(z2) AND SUM(z9) <= SUM(z3) AND SUM(z9) <= SUM(z4) AND SUM(z9) <= SUM(z5) AND SUM(z9) <= SUM(z6) AND SUM(z9) <= SUM(z7) AND SUM(z9) <= SUM(z8) AND SUM(z9) <= SUM(z10) THEN 9
            ELSE 10 END AS cycle
    FROM dbo.baseTable
    WHERE rowNum >= @offSet --row number of start of batch
    AND rowNum <= @limit --row number of end of batch
    --Update loop variables
    SET @offSet = @offSet + @batch
    SET @limit = @limit + @batch
    SET @iter = @iter + 1
END

--drop the temp table
DROP TABLE dbo.baseTable
--view the aggregated data
SELECT *
FROM dbo.aggTable
ORDER BY startTime
```

Please let me know if any further clarification is needed or if this question is inappropriate.

Comment: The first thing I would do is aggregate based on `group by (idx - 1) / 20`.  Several subqueries later I think you'll get what you want without any extra tables or while loops.

Comment: @avery_larry thanks for this suggestion, it seems to have worked perfectly. I wasn't aware you could do that nor do I understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard to do without sample data.  However, see what this does for you:

**untested** if that wasn't obvious

```
declare @date date = '2020-04-23'
declare @srcTable table (_time datetime, cycle_1 int, cycle_2 int, cycle_3 int
                        ,cycle_4 int, cycle_5 int, cycle_6 int, cycle_7 int
                        ,cycle_8 int, cycle_9 int, cycle_10 int, _date date)



insert into @srcTable
select getdate(), 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 9, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 9, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 5, 1, 2, 1, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 5, 1, 2, 1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 2, 1, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 0, 0, 1, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 2, 1, 2, 0, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 1, 1, 2, 0, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 2, 1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 6, 1, 2, 1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 5, 1, 2, 1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 0, 2, 0, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 0, 0, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 9, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 0, 2, 1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 2, 1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 2, 1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 2, 0, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 2, 0, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 0, 2, 1, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 2, 1, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 5, 0, 2, 1, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 0, 1, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'
union all
select getdate(), 0, 1, 2, 1, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 0, '2020-04-23'



select *
    ,(select min(cycle) --what a convoluted way to get the minimum cycle number that equals the maximum number of zero values
        from (values (z1, 1), (z2, 2), (z3, 3), (z4, 4), (z5, 5), (z6, 6), (z7, 7), (z8, 8), (z9, 9), (z10, 10)) AS value(amt, cycle)
        inner join (select (select max(amt) FROM (VALUES (z1), (z2), (z3), (z4), (z5), (z6), (z7), (z8), (z9), (z10)) AS value(amt)) amt) maxamt on maxamt.amt = value.amt) cycle
from (
    select min(_time) startTime, max(_time) endTime -- get first level of aggregated information
        ,sum(CASE WHEN Cycle_1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z1
        ,sum(CASE WHEN Cycle_2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z2
        ,sum(CASE WHEN Cycle_3 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z3
        ,sum(CASE WHEN Cycle_4 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z4
        ,sum(CASE WHEN Cycle_5 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z5
        ,sum(CASE WHEN Cycle_6 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z6
        ,sum(CASE WHEN Cycle_7 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z7
        ,sum(CASE WHEN Cycle_8 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z8
        ,sum(CASE WHEN Cycle_9 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z9
        ,sum(CASE WHEN Cycle_10 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z10
    from (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY _time) - 1 AS idx -- this gives us idx to aggregate on
        from @srcTable
        where _date = @date
    ) idx
    group by idx.idx / 20
) a
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I'm encountering a syntax error when implementing it. The error references the first open bracket on this line: ```from (values (z1, 1), (z2, 2), (z3, 3), (z4, 4), (z5, 5), (z6, 6), (z7, 7), (z8, 8), (z9, 9), (z10, 10)) AS value(amt, cycle)```.
I've tried removing that bracket and the corresponding close bracket but then the syntax error changed to reference the VALUES statement in the same line.

Comment: I made 2 changes.  The last select statement changed to `select *, row_number() ...` and the final parenthesis add a table alias.  I also added source data to confirm.